# How to upload a video file to website created using shiny package in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server, shiny

I am learning how to upload the video on the web using Shiny package in Rstudio. Following is my code for ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
headerPanel("Shiny App Example with Video and Image"),

 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file","Upload the file", multiple = T), 
  h6("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
  hr(),
  h5("Select the read.table parameters below"),
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
  br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices =     c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
  h6(" Powered by:"),
  tags$img(src='RStudio-Ball.png', height=50, width=50)

  ),

mainPanel(
  uiOutput("tb")
  )

)
))
```

The next code is for my server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input,output){

data <- reactive({
file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

})

output$filedf <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
input$file

})

output$sum <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
summary(data())

 })

output$table <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
data()
})

output$tb <- renderUI({
if(is.null(data()))
  h6("intro video", br(), tags$video(src='reactive.mp4', type="video/mp4", width="350px", height="350px", controls="controls"))
else
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
 })
})
```

I can launch the website. From there using the "Upload" button, I can navigate to the folder where my "reactive.mp4" file resides. But It provides the following error message in the main panel: "empty beginning of file"

In the Rstudio console the error is following:

```
Error in read.table(file = file1$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = input$header,  : 
empty beginning of file
Warning in run(timeoutMs) : line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\Lab-   User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMxaMe9/8fe8ab38479dea3acaf755a8/0'
```

I also tried changing the Encoding of the video file. Unfortunately, it does not play the video.

Solution:

I have not tried the solution given by the guy below. Because I do not want to upload a video on Youtube and then host it on the web.

So once, the user clicks the "Launch App" button on the Rstudio console. It will prompt the user to the local website. When I open the website using the browser (Button name is "Open in Browser", This can be found on the left hand corner). It will automatically show the website using browser. Sometimes in windows when you run from Rstudio locally and when you run in browser behavior is different.

Comment: Maybe you can use an iframe and upload it to youtube and have it this way?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To comeback to my 'quick' fix solution is to use `iframe`, you can upload the video onto youtube and then use the iframe to show it, something like this:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Welcome!"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel( HTML('<iframe width="600" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```